# iOS Routing App Registration

Tags: ios, mapkit, geojson

I am working on a routing app and I'm following the instructions found in the iOS Location and Maps Programming Guide.

I have registered my app as a routing app by performing the following:

1) Included the MKDirectionsApplicationSupportedModes key (supporting car, bus, pedestrian)

2) Included the Directions.geojson file (contents below)

3) Configured a special document type (MKDirectionsRequest) to handle incoming direction requests

4) Added the logic to handle the incoming directions in application openURL sourceApplication annotation

Specifically, Apple gives instructions on how to test in the simulator so I have also:

1) Set my debug scheme to use the Directions.geojson file provided

2) After installing the app on the device or simulator, I leave the app and launch the Maps app to specify the start and end points for directions.

At this point Apple's documentation indicates that if things are setup correctly I should see an option to choose my app (to send the directions to).  Apple says...

Your app should appear if its geographic coverage file is valid and contains the two specified points. If it does not, check the points for your geographical regions to make sure they are correct.

I'm not seeing my app as an option and i'm quite certain the geojson file is valid.  I have validated it at geojsonlint.com and can see a box covering the bulk of the United States.  I see that the file gets copied to the sim when installing; however, I still get no option in the Maps app to send the routed directions to my app.

Any ideas?

```
{ "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
                    [[[-124.747009,48.396385], [-64.525452,48.031264], [-72.597656,23.644524], [-125.354004,32.240683]]]
                    ]

}
```

Comment: Hi, working on the same thing. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I quote the documentation apple

Specifying the Geographic Coverage File Contents

The geographic coverage file must contain a single MultiPolygon shape that defines the boundaries of the supported geographic regions. A single multi polygon may contain multiple child polygons, each of which defines the boundaries around a single geographic region. Each child polygon contains four or more coordinate values that define the boundaries of the polygon. Per the GeoJSON specification, every child polygon must represent a closed region—that is, the first and last coordinate values must always be identical. Therefore, you must specify at least four points to define a triangular region, which is the simplest possible shape. Of course, you use more points to define more complex polygons.

Listing 7-2 shows an example of a geographic coverage file that specifies two separate regions: one around San Francisco and one around Chicago. Note that the coordinates for each region are surrounded by what seem to be an extra set of brackets. In each case, the first open bracket marks the beginning of the overall polygon shape, the second open bracket defines the beginning of the exterior bounding polygon, and the third open bracket marks the beginning of the first coordinate.

```
{ "type": "MultiPolygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [[[-122.7, 37.3], [-121.9, 37.3], [-121.9, 37.9], [-122.7, 37.9], [-122.7, 37.3]]],
    [[[-87.9, 41.5], [-87.3, 41.5], [-87.3, 42.1], [-87.9, 42.1], [-87.9, 41.5]]]
    ]
}
```

Therefore I think you don't close the region.

Comment: Apple has more restricted policy than the geojson standard specification!

Comment: In my case, both simulator and device successfully show my app among routing apps in the Maps app, however, after I publish app on AppStore, and install it, it is suddenly missing in the list. How can one explain that?